# Array representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i wonder what is the difference of array representation between `[]` and `(3) [Object,Object,Object]` ?

i have array of objects like:

```
var array = [{id: 1, text: 'a'}, {id: 2, text: 'b'}, {id: 3, text: 'c'}];
```

when i tried to `console.log(array)` at some line within my codes, sometime it printed as `[]` and sometime as `(3) [Object,Object,Object]`. the `[]` is not empty, though, when i expanded it on browser's console, both contain same values (3 objects).

in my case, when i'm using `var array` as data for my `select2` like this:

```
$('#elems').select2({
      data: array
});
```

if, when i `console.log(array)` and it shows as `(3) [Object, Object, Object]`, the `select2` gets the data, and the option would be `a,b,c`. but, when it shows as `[]` `select2` couldn't read the objects, thus, the option would be empty.

i wonder if `select2` reads `[]` as empty, although on browser's console `[]` is expandable and contains value. like this:

[image]

can anyone explain about this?

Comment: Have you clicked on the little `i` icon? The console is not standardized, so each browser can decide on its own how data is displayed.

Comment: @Xufox yeah, both shows the same message `value below was evaluated just now.` regardless of the browser, something prevent `select2` from reading `object` when the array shows as `[]`

Comment: I wonder if it's some sort of race condition. At the time console.log ran it was an empty array but by the time it rendered it had 3 items or something along those lines.

Comment: @mkaatman that was my thought too. then again, i tried to randomly put `console.log` at some lines within my code, some shows as `[]` and some didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timing issue. console.log runs before the items have been added. Run this snippet for an example. You'd have to hit the timing just right. Most likely a race condition.

```js
var array = [{id: 1, text: 'a'}, {id: 2, text: 'b'}, {id: 3, text: 'c'}];
console.log(array);

var array = [];
setTimeout(function(){
  array.push({id: 1, text: 'a'}, {id: 2, text: 'b'}, {id: 3, text: 'c'});
  }, 1000);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: i see, so it's a timing issue

Comment: 1000 ms on setTimeout does it exactly like you describe for me.

Answer (score 2):

The single-line display in the JavaScript console is generated at the moment you call `console.log()`.

When you click the arrow icon later, the multiline display is generated *at the time you click the arrow*.

That's why you see two different things: you've changed the array sometime after the original `console.log()` call but before you clicked the arrow.

If you want to see the complete array contents at it existed at the time of the `console.log()` call, a good way to do it is to use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( array, null, 4 ) );
```

If you're not sure why this happened, a likely bet is that you have some asynchronous operation that modifies the array after you made the original `console.log()` call. For example, a common mistake is to make an ajax call to populate a global variable, and then you try to immediately use that variable in your code after the ajax call returns - but this is *before* the data is ready and the ajax callback is called.

In this case you shouldn't be using a global variable at all. Instead, you should handle the data returned from the server within the ajax callback itself, or in a function that you call from within that callback. Don't try to store it in a global variable, and don't assume your other code knows when the data is ready. Access the data only within the callback.